# Корректна ли фраза: "Проверка сообщения проводится..."?

Tags: стилистика

> Проверка сообщения проводится целым комплексом проверочных действий, предусмотренных законом.

Answer (score 1):

Мне не нравится. Даже со скидкой на юридический сленг.
"В целях проверки осуществляется целый комплекс действий...". Как-то так.
Или, в зависимости от смысла, "Процедура проверки предусматривает...", "Мероприятия по проверке включают..."

Answer (score 0):

Можно лишь слегка подправить: Проверка сообщения проводится целым комплексом ОПРЕДЕЛЕННЫХ действий, предусмотренных законом.

Comment: Не проверяют "действиями". А если это допустить, то и исходный вариант ничем не хуже.

Comment: А разве проверка - это не действие?

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такой вариант.
Проверка сообщения проводится в процессе проведения комплекса проверочных мероприятий,предусмотренных...

Или:... с помощью целого комплекса проверочных действий, предусмотренных законом.

Comment: Вы привносите смысл, которого нет у автора.

Comment: Смысл именно тот: проверка с помощью мероприятий, имеющих целью проверить достоверность информации. В юриспруденции это называется проверочными действиями.Есть мероприятия проверочные, доследственные, а есть следственные. Например:Установить факт неправомерного доступа к компьютерной информации можно  в процессе проведения проверочных мероприятий в стадии возбуждения уголовного дела либо в ходе проведения ревизий, судебных экспертиз, иных следственных действий по уголовным делам, находящимся в производстве следователей, а также при проведении оперативно-розыскных мероприятий.

Comment: >>проверка **с помощью** мероприятий,  

На мой вкус вот только это "с помощью чего", а не просто "чем?" заставляет считать исходную фразу не совсем точно сформулированной с точки зрения русского языка.  Я лично старался исправить эту некорректность, сохранив смысл. Понятие "проверочные действия" и его уместность (а по вашим словам - даже необходимость) сомнений не вызывают. 
Короче, овцы и волки будут при своих, если: 

Проверка сообщения проводится с помощью целого комплекса предусмотренных законом проверочных действий.

Comment: Не понимаю, чем Вам не угодило слово "процесс" как "ход". "Процесс проведения  проверочных мероприятий" - юридическое клише, заменяющее слово "проверка"(процесс проверки) или "комплекс проверочных действий"- это одно и то же. В учебниках юристов это сплошь и рядом.